# how could I POST the data in DJANGO rest_frame?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to insert Track record through a condition but it does not happen. Please help me how could I do fix it?
this is views.py

```
class Track(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['post',]
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = Employee.objects.filter(username=kwargs.get('username'), password=kwargs.get('password'))
        if employee.exists():
            serializer_class = TrackSerializer
            try:
                if serializer_class.is_valid():
                    serializer_class.save()
                    return Response(serializer_class.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return Response(serializer_class.errors, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

urls.py

```
path('track/<username>/<password>/',views.TrackList.as_view(),name = 'track'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass data to your serializer

```
class Track(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['post',]
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = Employee.objects.filter(username=kwargs.get('username'), password=kwargs.get('password'))
        if employee.exists():
            serializer_class = TrackSerializer(data=request.data)
            try:
                if serializer_class.is_valid():
                    serializer_class.save()
                    return Response(serializer_class.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return Response(serializer_class.errors, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: And also it is a good practice to pass `context` to the serializer: `TrackSerializer(data=request.data, context=self.get_serializer_context())`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan sorry it is my mistake.